# Raspberry Pi touchscreen leftover graphics after a single click start

Tags: touchscreen, gui

I have a raspberry pi, compute module 4 with an i2c touchscreen configured to start programs by a single click since the double click method doesn't seem to work well for me.  There is no mouse or keyboard.

My program is started with a single click on a .desktop file located on the desktop. Call it [prog]. When I click on it a small gray graphic [prog] remains active on top of my UI.

Python 3.7 container UI using frames is the program operation if that helps.

I searched around a bit looking for an option to turn off the [prog] graphic when your finger is on the icon but haven't found it.

Location of the option or alternate method to "overwrite" the graphic is the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer relates to tooltips:

Make a copy of this file:
/home/pi/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel
and place it in:
/etc/xdg/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels
edit this file (or both, but I think this one is the key), search for tooltips and change from 1 to 0.

This method I found here:  https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=271916

Seems strange that taskbar tooltips settings relate to shutting off the name highlight when you hover over an desktop icon but a solution is a solution.